# Is it possible to capture Enter keypresses in C?

Tags: c, user-input, keypress, fgets

I want to write a C program that tokenizes a string and prints it out word by word, slowly, and I want it to simultaneously listen for the user pressing Enter, at which point they will be able to input data. Is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Update: see @modifiable-lvalue 's comment below for additional helpful information, e.g., using `getchar()` instead of getch(), if you go that route.

---

Definitely possible.  Just be aware that `gets()` may not be entirely helpful for this purpose, since `gets()` interprets enter not as enter per se, but as "now, I the user, have entered as much string as I want to". So the input gathered by `gets()` from pressing just an enter will appear as an empty string (which might be workable for you).
See: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/gets/.
But there are other reasons not to use gets()--it does not let you specify a maximum to read in, so it's easy to overflow whatever buffer you are using.  A security and bug nightmare waiting to happen.  So you want `fgets()`, which allows you to specify a maximum size to read in.  `fgets()` will place a newline in the string when an enter is pressed. (BTW, props to @jazzbassrob on fgets()).

You could also consider something like `getch()`--which really deals with individual key-presses (but it gets a bit complicated handling keys that have non-straightforward scan-codes). You may find this example helpful: http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/cpp/code/216732/reading-scan-codes-from-the-keyboard. But because of the scancodes issues, `getch()` is subject to platform details.

So if you want a more portable approach, you may need to use something heavier weight, but fairly portable, such as [ncurses](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/ncurses-intro.html).

I suspect you can do what you want with either `fgets()`, keeping in mind that enter will give you a string with just a newline in it, or `getch()`.

I just wanted you to be aware of some of the implementation/platform issues that can arise.

C can absolutely do this, but it's a little more complicated than one might guess at first attempt.  That's because terminal input is, historically, very platform dependent.

Comment: It is worth noting that `gets()` is considered extremely unsafe and in  modern C standards is totally deprecated.  You should always use `fgets` instead.

Comment: @jazzbassrob: Yup, you're right.  I should have put something like that in there.  I kind of am running out of steam.  As I was trying to orient OP on something seemingly so simple, I was getting a nice memory lane tour of why I'm happy to not actively write C any more.

Comment: @Resmar:  I concur with jazzbassrob.  If you do go the gets() route, then use `fgets()`, not really gets();

Comment: @Resmar, one of the reasons you want `fgets()` is that it a least lets you provide a limit on how much to read in.  gets() does not.  Therefore, it is utterly subject to potential buffer overflow and hacking.  getch() does not have the same problem, but has its own complexities.

Comment: Why are you referring to a C++ website for a C question? I suggest referring to an opengroup [manual for gets][1] or better yet [manual for fgets][2], instead. getch() is non-standard; I suggest using [getchar][3]() (and reading the manual *carefully*, because there are a few gotchas in that function too).

  [1]: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904975/functions/gets.html
  [2]: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904975/functions/fgets.html
  [3]: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904975/functions/getchar.html

Comment: @modifiablelvalue:  incorporated your input into the answer and referred readers to your comment, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the conio.h library and its use in game making.  You can compile with Borland.  That was my first experience in unbuffered input and listening for keypresses in real time.  There are certainly other ways though.